# Time capsule with Samsung Galaxy Note 8

Tags: time-capsule, file-sharing

I just bought a Galaxy note 8 and I am trying to access my files on my apple time capsule.  I just got my macbook air last christmas so I am not to familiar with how to use everything just yet.  I can access my files on my time capsule through my macbook and my husband can through his pc.  Is there a feature that needs to be enabled on the time capsule or my note for this connection to work?

Answer (score 7):

The only feature that needs to be enabled on the Time Capsule is the file sharing feature.

[image]

This will activate AFP and SMB Filesharing which allows your Mac, PC and Android Device to access the Time Capsule and use it as a NAS (basically the Time Capsule is a glorified NAS).

To access your file on the Time Capsule you need a SMB client for Android such as [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en):

1. Access the menu and select the LAN tab.
2. Perform a network scan and after a few seconds the time capsule should appear:

   [image]
   [image]
3. Select the computer and enter the login credentials to access your Time Capsule (username and password for the Time Capsule). You should see a folder that is named after the partition you see in the AirPort Utility when enabling the file sharing feature.